# Sorting an RDD in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a dataset listing general items bought by customers. Each record in the csv, lists items purchased by a customer, from left to right. For example (shortened sample):

```
Bicycle, Helmet, Gloves
Shoes, Jumper, Gloves
Television, Hat, Jumper, Playstation 5
```

I am looking to put this in an RDD in scala, and perform counts on them.

```
case class SalesItemSummary(SalesItemDesc: String, SalesItemCount: String)
val rdd_1 = sc.textFile("Data/SalesItems.csv")
val rdd_2 = rdd_1.flatMap(line => line.split(",")).countByValue();
```

Above is a short code sample. The first line is the case class (not used yet).
Line two grabs the data from the csv and puts it in an rdd_1. Easy enough.
Line three does flatmap, splits the data on the comma, and then does a count on each. So, for example, "Gloves" and "Jumper" above would have the number 2 beside it. The others 1. In what looks like a collection of tuples.
So far so good.

Next, I want to sort rdd_2 to list the top 3 most purchased items.
Can I do this with RDD? Or do I need to transfer RDD into a dataframe to achieve sort?
If so, how do I do it?

How do I apply the case class in line 1 for example to rdd_2, which seems to be a list of tuples? Should I take this approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The count in the case class should be an integer... and if you want to keep the results as an RDD, I'd suggest using `reduceByKey` rather than `countByValue` which returns a `Map[String, Long]` rather than an RDD.

Also I'd suggest splitting by `,`  rather than `,` to avoid leading spaces in the item names.

```
case class SalesItemSummary(SalesItemDesc: String, SalesItemCount: Int)

val rdd_1 = sc.textFile("Data/SalesItems.csv")

val rdd_2 = rdd_1.flatMap(_.split(", "))
                 .map((_, 1))
                 .reduceByKey(_ + _)
                 .map(line => SalesItemSummary(line._1, line._2))

rdd_2.collect()
// Array[SalesItemSummary] = Array(SalesItemSummary(Gloves,2), SalesItemSummary(Shoes,1), SalesItemSummary(Television,1), SalesItemSummary(Bicycle,1), SalesItemSummary(Helmet,1), SalesItemSummary(Hat,1), SalesItemSummary(Jumper,2), SalesItemSummary(Playstation 5,1))
```

To sort the RDD, you can use `sortBy`:

```
val top3 = rdd_2.sortBy(_.SalesItemCount, false).take(3)

top3
// Array[SalesItemSummary] = Array(SalesItemSummary(Gloves,2), SalesItemSummary(Jumper,2), SalesItemSummary(Shoes,1))
```